# Accessing Control.Focused true or false state from another thread

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a form whose focused state is checked in a method using:

```
if (!this.Focused)
{ 
   //do something
}
```

However, this also needs to be checked from another worker thread, and I am getting cross thread violations when I call if `(!this.Focused)` from another thread .  How can I access the true or false state of `this.Focused` boolean from another thread?  I am familiar with using delegates to update form controls from other threads, but I am having a real issue with this.  What am I missing? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

It's exactly the same - you just need to use the return value of [`Invoke`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyzhdc6b.aspx), which is the return value of the delegate:

```
Func<bool> func = () => this.Focused;
var focused = (bool) Invoke(func);
```

Answer (score 1):

What about this?

```
bool focused = false;

this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
{
    focused = controlname.Focused; 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
if (this.InvokeRequired)
{
    this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
    {
       focused = controlname.Focused; 
   });
}
else
{
focused = controlname.Focused;
}
```

check more about InvokeRequired http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37642/Avoiding-InvokeRequired